# How to check if element(s) exist in JSON array using jq, and put the corresponding object into a new file

Tags: json, jq

I am running curl commands on ~50 URL's and each have JSON that looks like this (but with different values for 'country' with each curl command, but the values for 'names' can possibly repeat or be unique:

e.g. one curl command can give JSON that looks like this:

```
{"names":["Mary","Tom","Sue","Rob"],"country":"USA"}
```

while the next curl command will give this:

```
{"names":["Sue"],"country":"Russia"}
```

and the next curl command will give this:

```
{"names":["Tom","Jenny"],"country":"Nigeria"}
```

and so on and so forth.

I have a separate list of names (e.g. Tom, Sarah, Jenny, Trinh, Nancy) and I want to find out if they're associated with a country in any of the JSON's I'm running the curl command on. If they exist in "names", I want to put the name of the person and the country into a new text file (or JSON file, doesn't matter - i just want it formatted properly), so at the end I have an output file that associates the name of the person and the country they belong to. If a country has multiple people, there shouldn't be a duplicate value for country in the output file; the names of the people should be listed under that one country.

I've tried multiple ways to solve this, but I'm not able to figure it out as it's my first time trying to write a script.

Last command that I tried:

```
curl "https://..." | jq -r 'select(.names[] as $a | ["Tom","Sarah","Jenny","Trinh","Nancy"] | index($a) | while read output; do tee -a listOfCountries; done; done
```

^This gave duplicates and I wasnt sure how to format the output so that there were spaces between each output and that the country had *only* the specific names of the people under it

The output file (given above example) should be something like:

```
USA: Tom

Nigeria: Tom, Jenny
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, it'll greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Side question: If the list of names to search is extremely long (100+ names), what is the best way to script this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all your JSON objects in a file, say  output.jsons:

```
jq -c -n --argjson list '[ "Tom", "Sarah", "Jenny", "Trinh", "Nancy"]' '
  (reduce inputs as $in ({}; reduce $in.names[] as $name (.; .[$name] += [$in.country]))) as $dict
  | reduce $list[] as $name ({}; 
      if $dict[$name] 
      then reduce $dict[$name][] as $country (.; .[$country] += [$name]) 
      else . end)
' output.jsons
```

produces:

```
{"USA":["Tom"],"Nigeria":["Tom","Jenny"]}
```

You can easily transform this into the desired output.

One way to ensure uniqueness of the elements of each array would be to append the following to the filter: `map_values(unique)`.

---

Re the side question: instead of --argjson you could use --argfile or --slurpfile.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! It's very helpful in understanding - I am running into an issue though, when running the above command, I'm getting error "(23) Failed writing body" {} error. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: That does not look like a jq error; it looks more like a `curl` error. Try reproducing the problem without using `curl`.

Comment: So instead of running curl, I just put the json's into a file and I'm catting it to the exact command you have given above (e.g. "cat testfile | jq -c -n ...."). However, running the command simply gives "{}" and when I check output.jsons, it is empty :( any ideas on why this could be happening? I did an exact copy paste and made no modifications (tried a few things but still didn't work)

Comment: You should check the contents of the file before running jq.

Comment: I have the file contents as this:


{"names":["Mary","Tom","Sue","Rob"],"country":"USA"}
{"names":["Sue"],"country":"Russia"}
{"names":["Tom","Jenny"],"country":"Nigeria"}


 (each json is on a new line, can't format on the comment here, sorry!) and when I run "cat testfile | jq -r .names", it returns the array of names. However running the command given above I just get the "{}" response and the file isn't populated. Is there anything that you see wrong with this? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Which file is not populated??? The given command reads from a file, but does not create or write to a file.

Comment: Ohh... that make A LOT more sense now! I wasn't familiar with the feeding the file in (at the end) part. Thanks a lot for your help!! you're very smart :D

Comment: I had another question as I'm going thru the code/trying to understand it. If I wanted to reverse the order (e.g. {"Tom":["USA", "Nigeria"],"Jenny":["Nigeria"]), which part of the code would have to be changed (and to avoid duplicates still)? From my understanding, "reduce $list[] as $name ({}; if $dict[$name]" is where the comparison with the name from $list and the name from "names" occurs - so would that change occur after that line/ what would it look like?

Comment: See update re uniqueness.

Comment: Hi @peak, my question was more along the lines of how to avoid duplicates within the output, rather than avoiding duplicates within the array itself, as in: 
{"Tom":["USA"]} {"Tom":["Nigeria"]} {"Jenny":["Nigeria"]} As you can see, Tom is occurring twice rather than how ideally it should be: {"Tom":["USA", "Nigeria"]}. TIA!